# Assumptions versus no assumptions - where do you draw the line?

Tags: architecture, coding-style, code-quality, coding-standards, clean-code

In our line of work as software engineers, we can write code that assumes various things outside its scope or architectural boundary, in order to save performance, time, and on defensive coding techniques that in the unlikely event of a meteor falling down - your program to still hold strong.

I'm not sure when working on a project, just what kind of assumptions are generally okay, and what aren't?

When writing a library, I'm more inclined to see logic behind writing code with zero assumptions, as you have no idea what the clients/users of your API will be doing, but I'm still not sure if that is actually a good thing to do.

The benefits of assuming something is true, are enormous, but every time we assume something, our code in an essence depends on that fact staying true as time passes.

A few examples of assuming various things:

If you know that method `A` will be called only from method `C` and `D`, which provide serialized access to the method `A`, you can decide to skip creating a synchronization specific to `A` in the event it is ever called from two places at the same time, because you know that access to it will always be serialized at a higher level (through `C` and `D`).

If your application will be hosted on Azure, or any trusted computer, where you know nobody would ever tamper with it - you wouldn't specifically need to handle events outside your control, such as a thread aborting due to someone on the host machine doing some evil things.

If you know that a given class that has been created by your application is registered as a singleton in a dependency injection system, you can skip writing defensive code in it that throws an exception in the event that fact is changed, because then the code/logic in that class would be wrong.

How much assumptions is too much? Where is the balance in writing code with no assumptions, to writing code with many assumptions?

Comment: There isn't a general answer to this, because software development varies so much, and in particular the cost of failure varies so much - if my meme generator crashes because it ran out of memory, nobody really cares. If my nuclear power plant control system crashes because it ran out of memory... oh dear.

Comment: @PhilipKendall we can all agree that our application running out of memory is a bad thing though. Generally speaking you should then strive for that to not happen. I don't think it has anything specific to do with assuming things when writing your code for handling that specific case? Still, I can see your point clearly, thank you!

Comment: @PhilipKendall if other applications eat up your memory and you get booted off, I can fully see what you meant. You were assuming you were the only process running on the system, and that the system itself wouldn't eat that much of a memory to make your job impossible. This is what my question is asking about.

Comment: Your main assumptions are: There are no bugs. The user does nothing stupid. There's no hacker attacking my app. Plus the assumption that the first three assumptions are wrong :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Actually I hope your nuclear power plant control system does crash when it runs out of memory. The alternative is that it quietly keeps running, while overwriting it's own memory, doing God knows what. At least a crash makes clear that it's time to start doing some things manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use common sense. Some assumptions (such as "input values entered by users won't contain SQL special characters") may have catastrophic consequences, others (endpoints A and B are called in that order, otherwise B will return a 500 server error) may just lead to slightly inconvenient error messages. Naturally, you want to always prevent catastrophic behavior.

Since assumptions are almost always implicit, making or not making them is rarely a deliberate decision. Therefore the best places to avoid them are in requirements analysis (don't leave too much underspecified and open to assumptions) and code review (where implicit assumptions made while coding may be identified). If you find that some code is based on assumptions, you need to weigh the cost of potential misbehavior against the cost of clarifying/eliminating the assumptions and changing the code to conform to the now hopefully precise requirements.